# How to assert in EasyMock if a method is called only once on a Object used in a method of a Mocked Object?

Tags: easymock

I have a class to test using EasyMock:

```java
public class Application {
    public void doSomething (AnotherObject o) {
        o.getA().perform();
    }   
}
```

In my JUnit test for `Application` I need to assert that `perform()` is called on an object returned by `o.getA()` and is called only once.

Does `AnotherObject` passed to `doSomething()` have to be mocked?

Is there a way to do this using EasyMock?

Answer (score 4):

You need to mock `A` and record that behavior. `AnotherObject` could be a mock or not. You just need `getA` to return the mock of `A`.

Then you will have something like:

```java
A a = createMock(A.class);
a.perform(); // this record one and only one call to perform()
replay(a);

AnotherObject another = new AnotherObject();
another.setA(a);

Application app = new Application()
app.doSomething(another);

verify(a); // this makes sure perform was call once instead of not at all
```